# Database not found in Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssas

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe does not work on a second machine as it works on the first.
It runs in connected mode with option RetainPartitions and generates a XMLA script for later deployment.

On the first machine it works fine:

```
Calling AnalysisServices.Deployment build via '& Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe "C:\My_Cube.asdatabase" /s:"C:\build_xmla.My_Cube.log" /o:"C:\My_Cube.xmla"'
Connecting to the myhost server
Database, My_Cube, found on server, myhost. Applying configuration settings and options...
    Analyzing configuration settings...
    Done
    Analyzing optimization settings...
    Done
    Analyzing storage information...
        First Cube
            F First measure group
                F First aggregation designs
                F First partitions
        Second Cube
            F Second measure group
                F Second aggregation designs
                F Second partitions
        Third Cube
            F Third measure group
                F Third aggregation designs
                F Third partitions
    Done
    Analyzing security information...
    Done
Generating processing sequence...
Saving deployment script to C:\My_Cube.xmla
Done
```

On the second machine it does not find the Database:

```
Calling AnalysisServices.Deployment build via '& Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe "C:\My_Cube.asdatabase" /s:"C:\build_xmla.My_Cube.log" /o:"C:\My_Cube.xmla"'
Connecting to the myhost server
Applying configuration settings and options...
    Analyzing configuration settings...
    Done
    Analyzing optimization settings...
    Done
    Analyzing storage information...
    Done
    Analyzing security information...
    Done
Generating processing sequence...
Saving deployment script to C:\My_Cube.xmla
Done
```

The second machine is connected to the SSAS instance (since the XMLA script execution works fine).
The User is Administrator in the SSAS instance.
None of the both machines is the machine is the sql server itself.

Do you have any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user had no permission to access the SSAS database.

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe does not return a error message.
It can be verified with a PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
Get-ChildItem SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\$TargetServer\Default\Databases
```